# Exchange 2013 - DNS Records for Accepting Multiple Domains

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, exchange-2013

I have an Exchange 2013 server accepting two domains: domain1.com and domain2.com.

All of the exchange services (OWA, ECP, POP3, SMTP, etc.) can be found via the address mail.domain1.com.

So, in the DNS records for domain1, I have the following entries:

MX Record
mail.domain1.com

A Record
mail.domain1.com -> (IP Address of Server)

CNAME Record
autodiscover.domain1.com -> mail.domain1.com

Now, for domain2.com, how would I set up the DNS records?  Would I have the autodiscover just be a cname for autodiscover.domain1.com?  Would this allow me to leverage the certificates that I have installed for domain1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a CNAME if you wanted, and if all the configuration for your new domain is exactly the same as that for your old one.  However, your certificates will not work unless they include the second domain as a subject alternative name; certificate validation is not affected by the use of CNAME records.

Other than that, you can set up the DNS records exactly as you did for the first domain, or you could create a CNAME for each of mail and autodiscover.